# UDP receiving buffer wrong size

Tags: c++, linux, udp

I am trying to determine a udp receiving queue size in cpp. The code that I am using is the following. To my understanding, the kernel will trying to set the buffer queue to either the minimum specified by the file */proc/sys/net/ipv4/udp_rmem_min* (4096 bytes) or the double of the size that I have specified. In my case, by using the command *netstat -nulc* and not reading any messages on the receiving queue, the receive queue specified by the command *netstat* grows until a size of 3968 bytes. However, when trying to get the size of the receiving queue by using `getsockopt(..., SO_RCVBUF, ...)` it reports 2240. Could someone explain me why?. The expected output from `getsockopt(..., SO_RCVBUF, ...)` should be 3968 or 4096 bytes.

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;


int main()
{
    std::string m_address = "192.168.2.100";
    int m_port = 8932;
    int m_sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in local_addr;
    socklen_t local_addrSize;
    int check_receive_buffer_size;

    // Create socket file descriptor
    m_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (m_sock < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WARNING\tFailed to create socket: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Setting receiving buffer size
    int receiving_buffer_size = 24; // set to 24 bytes
    if (setsockopt(m_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUFFORCE, &receiving_buffer_size, sizeof(receiving_buffer_size)) == -1) {
        std::cout<<"Failed to set the reading buffer size: "<<strerror(errno)<<std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Configure the local_addr
    local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    local_addr.sin_port = htons(m_port); // htons convert number to network byte order
    
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, m_address.c_str(), &(local_addr.sin_addr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WARNING\tFailed to convert address: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Bind the socket to ip local_addr and port
    if (bind(m_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WARNING\tFailed to bind socket: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    local_addrSize = sizeof(local_addr);

    while(true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
        // Get the size of the receiving UDP buffer to check
        socklen_t optlen = sizeof(check_receive_buffer_size);
        if (getsockopt(m_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void *)&check_receive_buffer_size, &optlen) == -1) {
            std::cout<<"Failed to read buffer size: "<<strerror(errno)<<std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        std::cout<<"Buffer size: "<<check_receive_buffer_size<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the `getsockopt(..., SO_RCVBUF, ...)` will give you the size `2240`? Is it possible for you to create a proper [mre], and copy-paste the full and complete actual as well as expected output from that program?

Comment: Yeah, I mean `getsockopt(..., SO_RCVBUF, ...)` .  I have edited my post so that it gives more information about it . Let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: It's probably really 2x2240=4480 and the next message didn't fit so it didn't get beyond 3968. Why are you using such a tiny size as 24? Most people find the defaults far too small. Set it to something reasonable like 64k or even 1M.

Comment: My messages are really small and I need to empty the buffer to get the latest message, so the smaller the time to empty the buffer the better.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It doesn't take any longer to remove a small message from a large buffer than from a small one, and a small one drastically increases the chance of data loss.

Comment: To empty the receiving buffer I am reading the buffer, I did not discover a way to flush the receiving buffer in cpp. Hence, reading a big buffer takes more time than reading a small buffer, is it right?

Comment: Moment please. This is UDP. You can only read one datagram at a time. If your datagrams are 24 bytes, that is how many bytes you will remove from the buffer on each read, at the most.

Comment: What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you feel the need to "flush the receiving buffer"? I just don't see any need to do that, and reading from a "buffer" is not coupled to the size of the buffer. A "buffer" is nothing more than an array of bytes, reading from it is like using a pointer to such an array to fetch a certain number of bytes and then modifying the pointer.

Comment: The receiving buffer queue is accumulating too much messages and as a consequence when I get the messages they are old. So to avoid this situation I reduce the size of the receiving buffer queue as much as possible. Apart from reducing the queue, I try to flush the buffer by reading the messages from the queue.

Comment: However, to read the messages from the receiving queue I perform the following, which needs in my case a vector of uint8_t. `std::vector<uint8_t> v_trash(check_receive_buffer_size*3);
    valread = recvfrom(m_sock, v_trash.data(), v_trash.max_size(), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&local_addr, &local_addrSize);` And here is where it takes more time to copy the info into the vector.

Comment: That seems like a latency problem in your program, like you don't have time to process all that's coming in a timely fashion. Do the messages have any kind of time-stamp, when they were sent? If they do, then you could just simply discard the messages that are too old instead of attempting to process them. Otherwise either update your protocol to include something like that, or improve your code doing the processing of the incoming messages to be quicker (perhaps use threads to process messages in parallel?)

Comment: "As a consequence when I get the messages they are old." So you need to read faster, "So to avoid this situation I reduce the size of the receiving buffer queue as much as possible." That doesn't avoid the situation at all. All it accomplishes is that you are causing the *newest* messages to be thrown away. You have some fundamental misunderstandings here. Try it with a 1M receive buffer and optimize your receive loop as much as possible. Post it here, even.

Comment: I could not agree more with @user207421 about the fundamental misunderstanding. Do you know any good resources?

Comment: NB Don't post code in comments. It is a complete waste of (a) your time, (b) space, (c) our bandwidth, and (d) our time. You can see for yourself that it is totally illegible. But, from the little I can make of it, you are allocating a new buffer per receive. This also is a waste of time. Try a byte array, allocated outside the read loop.